# jquery autocomplete on select box change

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

My HTML

```
Unit : <select name="unit_id" id="unit_id">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="1a">1/A</option>
    <option value="1b">1/B</option>
    <option value="1c">1/C</option>
    <option value="1d">1/D</option>
    </select>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function(){ 

$('#unit_id').autocomplete(
{
source: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/autocomplete/find_customer_name",
select: function(event, ui)
{
document.getElementById('customer_id').value = ui.item.customer_id;
document.getElementById('customer_name').value = ui.item.customer_name;
document.getElementById('customer_name1').value = ui.item.customer_name;
document.getElementById('dsp_due').innerHTML = ui.item.due_balance;
document.getElementById('dsp_custp').innerHTML = ui.item.package_name;

}
});
```

});

I want to use my autocomplete in a Select box . same code works fine in a input.text box but i need it as a select box. any help ? 
Thanks

Comment: try [this](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/)

Comment: is the `find_customer_name` action a valid JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the previously referenced [select 2 3.3](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) but found twitter's [typeahead](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) to be more to my liking. Both would work great in this instance. Why reinvent the wheel right?